# Sharing data between Multiple Craft 3 CMS instances

Tags: craft3, plugins, database

I am not asking about [multi-site](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html).  Rather, I am curious if there is existing support for "sharing" data across unique Craft 3 installs.

For instance, let's say he have 2 Craft 3 installs running as headless CMS.  **Craft CMS A** has a Glossary Section with Glossary Term Entries, each Entry localized in English and Spanish.  **Craft CMS B** has a News Section with News Post Entries, each Entry localized in English and Spanish.  If these Sections were in the same CMS it would be trivial to include hyperlinks to Glossary Terms in a News Post.  But how can I include hyperlinks to **CMS A** Glossary Terms in **CMS B** News Posts?  Is there native, or existing plugin for creating a "connection" between separate Craft CMS Sections & Entries?  I think I'm looking for something like the [Connect plugin](https://nystudio107.com/docs/connect/) but at the CMS Dashboard level, rather than in Twig templating.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything that does what you are asking. Since you're running headless Craft, it seems safe to assume that you have a public API that could return **CMS A** Glossary Terms. You could then write a custom field type, via a module/plugin installed on **CMS B**, that hits the **CMS A** API endpoint and displays the resulting glossary terms in a dropdown field, for example.

Comment: Interesting workaround.  Excellent idea.  Yes, indeed it is serving over graphQL.  Is that "populate a dropdown with response from external API" behavior something configurable via some existing plugin, or are you suggesting one would need to develop a new plugin to make this do?

Comment: Oooo, this is looking very much "in the ballpark": https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me

Comment: I was suggesting developing a custom plugin for the custom field type.